# Запуск проекта Yii2 на локалке с bitbucken

Tags: php, yii2

Помогите, люди добрые!
Вторые сутки ломаю мозг: что-бы это значило?
Есть проект Yii2 на bitbucken, его надо стянуть и установить на локалке. К нему есть дамп базы. Проверка работоспособности - возможность по заданому логину и паролю войти и залогиниться.
Все работает, но не логинит. 
Скачала с git основной пакет, через композер стянула все остальное. Скачала дамп, импортировала. Зашла в  .env и прописала свои настройки базы, запустила миграции, создала виртуальный хост. Картинки, слайдеры, ссылки ...
Я понимаю, что логинятся по своему на каждом сайте, но если это задание типа типовое, то куда смотреть, где искать ошибку или порядок дейчтвий неправильный?

Заранее благодарна за ответ.

---

Ссылка которая отправляет запрос с моими данными ведет на Site/login отдуда (редиректом) на страницу приветствия. Там только один индекс. Проверила через echo везде попадает по адресу и должно отобразить Welkome! но отображает предупреждение, что время сеанса истекло. Где находится функция которая, обрабатывает запрос до вышеуказанных, я не нашла. Но знаю, что данные на самого юзера хранятся в базе, а приложение еще куда то стучится через прикрученные API. В роутах нашла, что забыть пароль и стучаться после этого можно только через 1 день. Но как??? как оно работает??? Ф может кто-то сказать, я хотя бы правильно его ставила? Ну хотя бы часть моих действий ?...

Comment: можете предоставить ссылку на репозиторий?

Comment: Не могу. Там доступ запаролен. Человек пароли регулярно меняет так как проект рабочий. У американцев с этим строго. Другой соискатель залогинился с теми же данными, выполнил также еще что-то, но на работу тоже не взяли. я нашла работу попроще